# nuxtjs 3 add external javascript

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I tried to add an external javascript file to **nuxt.config.ts**.
but nuxt didn't load the file.

**nuxt.config.ts** file:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({

    css: [
        'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
    ],
    script: [
        {
            src: 'script.js',
        }
    ],
    vite: {
        define: {
            'process.env.DEBUG': false,
        },
    }
})
```

Comment: Where is the file located? In `public`? Tried with `/script.js`?

Comment: yes I already tried but didn't work. I guess because nuxt.config is a typescript file it doesn't work but i can't fix it.
@kissu

Comment: TS is not a blocker by itself (types is something else). Did you tried [that one](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/1365#discussioncomment-1524171)? What kind of issue do you have exactly? Can you see something in your network tab?

Comment: Didn't work again. there is no request in the network tab, but i have this error in my ide: 
"TS2345: Argument of type '{ css: string[]; script: { src: string; defer: boolean; }[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NuxtConfig'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'script' does not exist in type 'NuxtConfig'." @kissu

Comment: Yeah, it provides you an explanation so far. As shown in my previous comment, `script` should be inside of `meta`.

Answer (score 9):

The correct way to load scripts in Nuxt 3 is by using the `head` object in `app` ([See more in Official Docs here](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/nuxt-config#head))

In your case, This should work.

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  app: {
    head: {
      link: [
        { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' },
      ],
      script: [{ src: 'script.js' }],
    },
  },

  vite: {
    define: { 'process.env.DEBUG': false },
  },
});
```

`head` contain `meta`, `script`, `link`, `style` and `no-script` tags, so if you want to write any of them you'll use the same approach

Comment: worked for me on Nuxt 3 thank you

Comment: Where do I place script.js?

Comment: script.js the code is the path to the scrupt you want to include. So put it wherever you want then specify its path here

Comment: this works, but the thing is it will load on all pages/components unnecessarily . for example we want to use highchart and we want to load it on just dashboard component we can not do that , i have tried adding useHead but it didnt worked for me , it gives different issues 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76708986/external-script-doesnt-always-loads-when-we-navigate-between-components-nuxt-3?noredirect=1#comment135239853_76708986
see if you can help here

Answer (score 2):

I tried many ways and this is the only way it's worked.

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
css: [
    '@/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css'
],
app: {
    head: {
        script: [
            {
                src: '_nuxt/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',
            }
        ],
    }
}
})
```

Comment: What's the exact version of your Nuxt package?

Comment: 3.0.0-rc.13 @kissu