# external script doesn't always loads when we navigate between components nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, vue-component, nuxt3

external script doesn't always loads when we navigate between components nuxt 3 , i have created component
dashboard/index.vue
added this code

```
useHead({
    script: [
        {
            src: 'https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js',
            type: 'text/javascript',
            async: true,
            body: true
        },
    ],
});
```

this it the function i am using in onMounted

```
const initializeCharts = () => {
    window.Highcharts.chart('highchart-1', {
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            height: 310
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            accessibility: {
                description: 'Months of the year'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature'
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value}°'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            crosshairs: true,
            shared: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            spline: {
                marker: {
                    radius: 4,
                    lineColor: '#666666',
                    lineWidth: 1
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            marker: {
                symbol: 'square'
            },
            data: [5.2, 5.7, 8.7, 13.9, 18.2, 21.4, 25.0, {
                y: 26.4,
                marker: {
                    symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png)'
                },
                accessibility: {
                    description: 'Sunny symbol, this is the warmest point in the chart.'
                }
            }, 22.8, 17.5, 12.1, 7.6]

        }, {
            name: 'Bergen',
            marker: {
                symbol: 'diamond'
            },
            data: [{
                y: 1.5,
                marker: {
                    symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/snow.png)'
                },
                accessibility: {
                    description: 'Snowy symbol, this is the coldest point in the chart.'
                }
            }, 1.6, 3.3, 5.9, 10.5, 13.5, 14.5, 14.4, 11.5, 8.7, 4.7, 2.6]
        }]
    });
```

when we navigate from one page to dashboard page it doesn't loads , when we reload the dashboard page then it works fine as expected

i have tried adding onMounted, onBeforeUpdate and many other lifecycle hooks but at the end i see the same error,
i am using nuxt3
here is the stackblitz code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-kqvufh

Comment: Are you using NuxtLink to navigate from one page to another? Your codes are working. You may need to check what's causing the issue or add more info or codes related to the issue.

Comment: updated the code but basically the issue is the script is not loading , i can not see that script in head or before body , but when i reload the page then everything is perfect ... i am using nuxlink yes

Comment: Hey, can you setup a minimal reproduction on stackblitz so It becomes easier for me and others to check the code and try out solutions that may help you?

Comment: @MuhammadMahmoud yes shared :)

Comment: @samairali I'll try it out as soon as I could and get back to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error happens because your using the `initializeCharts` in the page `onMounted` hook which may happen before fetching the script from the CDN. This leads to `initializeCharts` not finding the `window.Highcharts` provided by the script.

The solution is ensure running the function only after the script is fetched. This can be done by calling `initializeCharts` inside the `onload` hook in `useHead` like the following

```js
useHead({
  script: [
    {
    src: 'https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js',
    onload: () => { initializeCharts() },
    }
  ]
});

onMounted(() => {
  // This is no longer needed and can be removed
  // initializeCharts(); 
});
```

Check this [Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-aqw7e7?file=pages%2Fdashboard.vue) with the applied changes, you'll find the script tag present in both cases (directly opening the dashboard page or naviagting to it from the index page using the link)

Comment: no not exactly , the issue is it is not loading the highcart.js script when we navigate from one page to other , if we refresh the page everything works .. make sense ?

Comment: yes, because on refereshing the page loads the scripts first including the highchart and then gets rendered on the page. When visiting the index page then navigating to dashboard the page is already there but the script is yet to be loaded, that's the problem. Have you tried my solution and didn't work?

Comment: yes i have tried your solution , it think the issue is not clear to you :)
the script that is the link https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js
you will not be able to see it in the inspect element in the browser when you navigate from home to dashboard , but when you reload the dashboard page then you can see this <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"> , hope it will be clear now for you

Comment: @samairali It's there my friend how else would the chart appear.  After updating the code as suggested there's a `<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>` when you directly open the dashboard page OR naviagte to it from the index by clicking the dashboard link.

Comment: @samairali I've updated the answer with a stackblitz link, check it out and you'll find that the script tag is present in both cases

Comment: i have copied the exact same thing but it is not working for me .. for the work around i have added head in nuxt config but after that it loads the script on all pages/components i dont want that , for learning i am trying to make it load on specific component ...

Comment: Have you tried the stackblitz link and found the script in both cases? This means that the problem is on your end and maybe you're doing something wrong at your local device